# Deploy artifacts using CI/CD pipeline to AWS EC2

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, cicd

I'm converting a legacy app from custom build to GIT Lab CI/CD. I was able to create stages such as build and security scans, as well as upload to Nexus with custom versioning.

The application is a spring boot application, so the final artifacts include a.jar file and script.sh files.

Our target platform is an AWS EC2 instance, and while looking for a solution, we came across a few approaches, such as SSH into the target and copying the required files. as well as Ansible Tower as another option for advancing the required artifacts.

SSH approach explained link:
https://medium.com/hackernoon/configuring-gitlab-ci-yml-150a98e9765d

High level flow:

Code -> GIT -> Commit Branch to feature branch -> Build -> Publish to Nexus Repo and version -> Deploy to dev (Manual) -> deploy to staging (Manual) -> deploy to production (Manual)

We are attempting not to push code into different branches such as staging/production or merge requests, but rather to treat the image/artifact posted in the Nexus as a final production image that must be pushed to all environments.

Is there a better way to deploy code from Nexus Repo to an EC2 instance than SSH or Ansible?

Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? How to build an entire CI/CD pipeline on AWS?

Comment: No, AWS code deploy is not available as service for us. Instead looking for any other better deployment approach which would help to push the code from Nexus to EC2 instance.

Comment: what about build an EC2 image then deploy this image on different env ? https://aws.amazon.com/image-builder/

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm more looking for pushing only the code/artifacts instead of building the whole EC2 AMI image. I also came across pushing to S3 bucket and pull from S3 but that again not aligned more from repository maintenance which we can show case for other requirement like audits.